# Firestore addSnapshotListener Replacing Object Data upon New Object Entry

Tags: swift, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function;

```
func observePosts() {
    let postReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").limit(to: 20).order(by: "postTimestamp", descending: true)
    postReference.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        } else {
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
            let models = snapshot.documents.flatMap({Post(dictionary: $0.data())})
            self.posts = models
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.feedCollection.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns all of the documents under the collection.

However, when I add another object as per the below;

```
uploadMedia { (url) in
        if url != nil {
            let postIDReference = self.postsReference.collection("Posts").document().documentID
            self.postsReference.collection("Posts").document().setData([
                "postID" : postIDReference,
                "postImageURL" : url!,
                "postTimestamp" : 1234567890
                ], completion: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error as Any)
                    return
                } else {
                    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This overrides a cell with the new setData object.  I've read some similar issues on SO but most relate to not having an auto-ID key which

```
self.postsReference.collection("Posts").document().setData(
```

gives me.

What I've tried:

Terminating the app and reopening gives me all the objects in Firestore.
Firestore dashboard has all the objects (so there isn't a problem with missing data).

Here are my Delegate & Datasource Methods

```
    extension FeedController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource 
{
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let feedCell = feedCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"cell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        let post = posts[indexPath.item]
        feedCell.post = post
        return feedCell
    }
}
```

CollectionView Cell

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
    
    var post: Post? {
        didSet {
            guard let post = post else { return }
            let postImageURL: URL = URL(string: (post.postImageURL))!
            postImage.sd_setImage(with: postImageURL) { (image, error, cache, url) 
in
                self.postImage.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe there's no need as when there's a new object the snapshot should update and call observePosts() again.  Which has a .reloadData in it.  Furthermore, when adding a new post on the device the simulator is showing the same behavior.  I believe the problem is with reading the data rather than writing it.

Comment: For clarification: Is your problem that when you create new documents, they replace existing cells in your UITableView? (But there are new documents within Firestore?)

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what is happening.  No matter how many objects I upload it always overrides one of the existing objects.

Comment: Have you tried to compare your `self.posts` between executions of the the closure? You can try to isolate the problem to a UITableViewDataSource / loading vs Firestore retrieval.

Comment: I've just checked my self.posts.count. Initially, I had 10 posts.  I created and uploaded another.  It printed in the console self.posts.count as 11.  However, in my collectionView, I only have 10 posts? Again killing the app and reopening it gives me 11 in my collectionView.

Comment: *Sorry, should not have assumed UITableViewDataSource* - I would focus your troubleshooting on the collection view's datasource methods.

Comment: Will add my delegate methods to the question.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my custom flowLayout.  I believe I need to invalidate the layout when retrieving new items.